# Regex: pass a query string if and only if it includes some subsequent parameters?

Tags: regex, logging, papertrail-app

I'm trying to use PaperTrail's filter logs tool to filter out specific paths using RegEx. My log string could look like one of the below:

Should NOT pass and NOT be logged

```
Sep 03 10:12:40 lastmingear heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/orders/SOME_ID?key=USER_KEY" host=www.lastmingear.com...
```

Should PASS, and BE logged

```
Sep 03 10:12:40 lastmingear heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/orders/SOME_ID?key=USER_KEY&log=true" host=www.lastmingear.com...
```

The only difference is that the path where I want it to BE logged has an additional params `log=true`. So the RegEx statement should read verbally, like:

> IF a `key=USER_KEY` is provided, then do NOT pass into logs UNLESS there is also a `log=true`

Comment: If you format your code to eliminate scrolling, you make it easier for others to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex, but it's usually considered a bad practice to match query strings against a pattern like that. What if the parameters are in a different order? What if there are other parameters in-between them? What if they're URL-encoded?

Instead, you might consider parsing the query string and analyzing the key-value pairs:

```
require 'uri'

def log?(log_line)
  path = log_line[/path="([^"]+)"/, 1]
  uri = URI(path)
  params = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h
  not params['key'] or params['log'] == 'true'
end
```

UPDATE: This is a tricky regex problem to solve because there isn't really a way to say if-this-then-that-or-etc. in a regex. You can use assertions but they will only get you so far. You essentially must enumerate all of the patterns you want to pass. I want to stress that this is fairly brittle and you'll want to keep an eye on it over time to see if there is any variance in the pattern.

This pattern matches log lines for the /orders route with a numeric order number, with an optional query string. If the query string is provided, it must match one of the patterns provided. If a numeric key number is provided, log must be true.

```
/path="\/orders\/\d+
  (?:\?
    (?:(?!(?<=[?&])key=\d+(?=[&"])).)*?
    |(.+?&)?log=true(&.+?)?
  )?
"/x
```

Comment: yes but in this case, I don't have this option; papertrail gives you a single line of regex, you can't run a method on it

Comment: Ah, I was confused by the ruby tag and Ruby in the description. Sorry about that.

Comment: but it still sounds like you're a regex wizard who might be able to help??? any one line that makes this PASS `key=USER_KEY&log=true` and this FAIL `key=USER_KEY`? I see your point about the order of the params, but honestly since hte only person using `log=true` would be me, I can remember hte rule

Comment: @james Sorry, I was away from my computer. I just updated my answer with a regex solution. Take a look... I'm guessing it still needs some work, but hopefully this gives us a starting point.

Comment: @james Oops, I missed something pretty important. It's fixed now!

Comment: Has @mwp solved your problem? If so, I am deleting my answer because clarification of your problem has rendered my answer incomplete.

Comment: hi @Mwp thanks for the insight! i thought this would be much easier, because i was thinking well you can write regex to match `bop` and `top` but not `cop` but I guess since the required param comes at the end that's what makes it difficult. In any case, this kind of worked, but more importantly gave me a totally (not related to this question) different idea on how to solve this. thanks!

Comment: @james You're welcome. If you decide to try the regex solution again, let me know where this solution falls short and we can work on enhancing it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

While I prefer @mwp's answer for the reason he has given, what is wrong with the following regex:

```
/path="[^"]+?\&log=true.*?"/
```

Match all non quotes non-greedily until you find `&log=true` followed by anything non-greedily then a closing quote.

Comment: thanks! I'm testing this in Rubular and can't seem to get it to pass? So this should match `at=info method=GET path="/orders/SOME_ID?key=USER_KEY&log=true" host=www.lastmingear.com` but it doesn't seem to?

Comment: oh also I should be a bit more clear... the restriction on `log true` ONLY happens if there's a `key`. I.e., if there are parameters WITHOUT any key, they should go and get logged, but IF there's a key, then there HAS to ALSO be a `log true` to get logged